# в чем отличие этих уровней тестирования друг от друга?

Tags: тестирование

Подскажите, в чём отличие этих двух уровней тестирования по стандарту ISTQB

- Integration Testing
- Component Integration Testion

Разве это не одно и тоже ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Компонентное интеграционное тестирование** — проверяет связи между разными компонентами внутри одной системы. *Может быть автоматизировано.*

---

Предположим, у вас есть сайт, на котором есть форма заказа.

После нажатия на кнопку "Создать":

1. браузер (frontend) шлет данные о заказе на backend
2. backend обрабатывает данные и сохраняет их в базу данных

---

В этом случае, можно выделить 3 компонента и 2 интеграции между ними.

Компоненты:

1. Frontend
2. Backend
3. Database

Интеграции:

1. Frontend -> Backend
2. Backend -> Database

---

Проверка связей ("стрелочек" в блоке Интеграции) - и есть **Компонентное интеграционное тестирование**.

---

Например, для первой интеграции (Frontend -> Backend) можно проверять:

1. Правильность передаваемых данных (все ли отправили?)
2. Факт получения данных (пришли ли данные вообще, или мы отправили их куда-то не туда?)
3. Правильности приема данных (после получения данных - как на них отреагировала принимающая сторона? Упали ли ошибки?)
4. ...

---

**Системное интеграционное тестирование** — проверяет связи между подсистемами / системами. *Не всегда можно автоматизировать, так как часто интеграция происходит с внешним сервисом, к которому мы не имеем доступа.*

---

С точки зрения проверок - тоже самое: проверяем передачу / прием данных.

Отличие заключается в том, что если в первом случае мы проверяли связи между **компонентами ОДНОЙ системы**, то теперь нам нужно проверить связи между **разными системами**.

---

Например, наш сайт - это одна система.

Он передает некие данные в 2 другие системы:

1. Google Analytics - данные о клиентах
2. Payment Processing - данные об оплате заказов

---

Проверка интеграции нашего сайта с этими двумя внешними системами и будет называться **Системное интеграционное тестирование**.

---

Определения брал здесь - [Уровни тестирования](https://beqa.pro/blog/testing-levels/#integration-testing)

---

*важно понимать, что определение интеграционного тестирования будет зависеть от определений: **компонент**, **система** и **под-система**. В разных контекстах это могут быть разные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Интеграционное тестирование (integration testing): Тестирование, выполняемое для
обнаружения дефектов в интерфейсах и во взаимодействии между интегрированными
компонентами или системами. См. также тестирование интеграции компонентов,
системное интеграционное тестирование.

Тестирование интеграции компонентов (component integration testing): Тестирование,
выполняемое для выявления дефектов в интерфейсах и взаимодействии между
интегрированными компонентами.

Источник
https://www.gasq.org/files/content/gasq/downloads/certification/ISTQB/Glossary/ISTQB_Glossary_Russian_v2_0.pdf

Немного понятнее
Допустим система обработки писем и в ней есть компоненты отвечающие за получение и за отправку, это разные микросервисы(читай компоненты) но они работают внутри одной системы и тестирование их интеграции как раз будет "Тестирование интеграции компонентов" а вот если мы тестируем взаимосвязь системы обработки писем и допустим внешней системы шифрования писем, то это уже будет "Интеграционное тестирование"

Comment: Как Итог одно может в целом для систем, а второе только для компонентов

Comment: Обилие англословий понимания не привносит. Можете расширить ответ своими словами, возможно на примере?

Comment: Ну вот есть допустим система обработки писем и в ней есть компоненты отвечающие за получение и за отправку, это разные микросерсивы(читай компоненты) но они работают внутри одной системы и тестирование их интеграции как раз будет "Тестирование интеграции компонентов" а вот если мы тестируем взаимосвязь системы обработки писем и допустим внешней системы шифрования писем, то это уже будет "Интеграционное тестирование"

Comment: Вот, весьма понятное объяснение "на пальцах". Добавьте в ответ его.